# Linking Tracking Data back to Salesforce CRM from non-sync Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

Using the Filtered Data Extension, is there any way to link tracking data from the subscriber with the contactId in order to sync it back to Sales Cloud?

We were using Salesforce Data as entry data because we need to have tracking data in the CRM.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for a journey, user initiated send, triggered sent, other send method? If your tracking data is not being sent back to Sales Cloud, try using a Salesforce data extension. If that still does not work, I would replace your data filter with a SQL query as that has always worked for me with Salesforce Data extensions for individual sends and with any data extension for journey builder sends.